# How to create Auto generate number series (as 00001,00002) in SQL Server without ID in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I want to create or generate billing no series as 00001/SC,00002/Sc......so on. IN my database table ID column is not available so now what can I do
Thanks

Comment: You can manually calculate the value and define a UDF for this. which would get total count and append zeroes before the total count

Answer (score 1):

If the table doesn't have got an Id column, the SEQUENCE property is useful for creating incremental value.

[how to learn details about MSSQLServer Sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

How to create a SEQUENCE

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[SequenceID]  AS [int]  START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 2147483647  CACHE GO
```

How to get a new SEQUENCE

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[SequenceID]
```

Every executing the previous query(`...next value....`), MSSQL Server gives a new Id.

How to create a new billing Id

```
select Right('000000' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[SequenceID]), 6)+'/SC' AS BillingId
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a before insert trigger. You can read more about triggers [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/triggers-in-sql-server/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of 2 methods you can do this.
1:- With the help of auto generate ID in your database table
> SqlCommand bill = new SqlCommand("SELECT (RIGHT ('000000'+ CAST ((IsNull(Max(ID), 0) + 1) AS varchar), 6)+'/Sc') from tableName", cons);

```
           > string result = (string)bill.ExecuteScalar(); (in result we store the value of bill and then send into database).
```

> > cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillNo", result);(sending into database)

Answer (score 0):

2nd with the help of RowCount() method...
cn.Open();

```
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO demo(Bill_No,Name) values(@cust_id,@Name)",cn);
         //Counting Rows
         SqlCommand CountingRows = new SqlCommand("Select COUNT(*) FROM demo",cn);
         int result = Convert.ToInt32(CountingRows.ExecuteScalar());
         if(result+1<10)
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_id", ("0000") + (result + 1) + ("/Sc"));
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         
         }else if(result+1 >=10 && result+1<100)
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_id", ("000") + (result + 1) + ("/Sc"));
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         }
         else if (result + 1 >= 100)
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_id", ("00") + (result + 1) + ("/Sc"));
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         
         }
     [enter image description here][1]
           
         cn.Close();
```